# In which condition my numpy 2d array is automatically converted into 1d array?

Tags: python, numpy

A.shape = (5,2)

which operation lead to return 1d array like **(4,)** 
like a.dot(b) or numpy.exp(a) etc

**Note:** No use of numpy.reshape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy function that leads to this result beside for numpy.reshape() is :

1. **np.ravel()**
2. **np.flat()**

or in some case when you select column from matrix its return it into vector (1 Dimension) like

1. **a[ : ,i ]** where i is index of selected column

No any other function like np.dot ,np.exp lead to convert it into 1D array.